# Alt+Left and Right arrow keys change from GUI to console

Tags: shortcut-keys, shortcuts, virtual-console

I'm using Ubuntu GNOME 16.10 and recently I noticed that by pressing Alt+Left changes from the GUI to the tty.

I use that shortcut regularly and this behavior interferes with my workflow.

How can I disable it?

Comment: see https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/146060/55065 for a one-time fix

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Only workaround I can find is to run `sudo kbd_mode -s`, which fixes it in the current session for me.

I'm not sure how to use that to fix it permanently, or what the root cause is.

Comment: It seems like the behavior doesn't always happen. When it shows up I'll give it a try. For now I'll accept your answer! Thank you!

Comment: It happened again and your solution worked. I'm lucky that it only sometimes happens to me.

Answer (score 0):

I got here because my `alt+left` was not working as a custom shortcut on phpstorm on ubuntu, but I realized that my problem was when I modified the default `alt` behavior to `key to chose the 3rd level` (to use accents with left alt).